# how can i store data in sim card from sim card application?

Tags: applet, javacard, apdu, sim-card

i am writing a sim card applet and i need to store data on sim card.

but i didnt do it. 
i found an example and use it but data disappear always when simulator restart.
i use "cmdPUTDATA(apdu);" method for save data and i use "cmdGETDATA(apdu);" method for save data.

here is my code and response;

```
     public void process(APDU apdu) {

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        if (apdu.isISOInterindustryCLA()) {
            if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] == (byte) (0xA4)) {
                return;
            }
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }

        switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {
            case INS_GET_BALANCE:
                getBalance(apdu);
                return;
            case INS_CREDIT:
                credit(apdu);
                return;
            case INS_CHARGE:
                charge(apdu);
                return;
//            case INS_SELECT:                      // it is a SELECT FILE instruction
//                cmdSELECT(apdu);
//                break;
//            case INS_VERIFY:                      // it is a VERIFY instruction
//                cmdVERIFY(apdu);
//                break;
//            case INS_PUTDATA:                     // it is a PUT DATA instruction
//                cmdPUTDATA(apdu);
//                break;
//            case INS_GETDATA:                     // it is a GET DATA instruction
//                cmdGETDATA(apdu);
//                break;
            default:
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
    }

//    @TransactionType(REQUIRED)
    //synchronized 
    private void credit(APDU apdu) {

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        byte numBytes = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC];
        byte byteRead = (byte) (apdu.setIncomingAndReceive());

        if ((numBytes != 2) || (byteRead != 2)) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_LENGTH);
        }

        short creditAmount = (short) ((short) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA] << (short) 8) | (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA + 1]));

        if ((creditAmount > MAX_BALANCE) || (creditAmount < (short) 0)) {
            ISOException.throwIt(SW_INVALID_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT);
        }

        if ((short) (balance + creditAmount) > MAX_BALANCE) {
            ISOException.throwIt(SW_MAX_BALANCE_EXCEEDED);
        }
        JCSystem.beginTransaction();
        balance = (short) (balance + creditAmount);
        JCSystem.commitTransaction();
    }

    private void getBalance(APDU apdu) {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        buffer[0] = (byte) (balance >> (short) 8);
        buffer[1] = (byte) (balance & (short) 0x00FF);
        //apdu.setOutgoingLength((byte) 2);        
        //apdu.sendBytes((short) 0, (short) 2);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, (short)2);
    }

    private void charge(APDU apdu) {        
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        byte numBytes = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC];
        byte byteRead = (byte) (apdu.setIncomingAndReceive());

        if ((numBytes != 2) || (byteRead != 2)) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_LENGTH);
        }

        short chargeAmount = (short) ((short) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA] << (short) 8) | (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA + 1]));

        if ((chargeAmount > MAX_BALANCE) || (chargeAmount < (short) 0)) {
            ISOException.throwIt(SW_INVALID_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT);
        }

        if ((short) (balance - chargeAmount) < 0) {
            ISOException.throwIt(SW_MIN_BALANCE_EXCEEDED);
        }
        JCSystem.beginTransaction();
        balance = (short) (balance - chargeAmount);
        JCSystem.commitTransaction();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your design is wrong, you should not use `static` keywords for what are basically fields (e.g. the `pin`, `memory` fields), otherwise it looks like you are on your way.

Comment: i referenced  it from http://www.wrankl.de and in my think its true.

Comment: Fine, if you don't want to listen. It's basic class design, everybody with any experience in Java will confirm I'm right here, and it is working perfectly if you refactor it to fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

constructor method and my other method is here.  between the "beginTransaction" and "commitTransaction" code, goto EEPROM persitent data. But it run only classic applet(java card api 3.0), it doesnt run Extendet Applet.

```
 private Akbil_Classic(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
            memory = new byte[SIZE_MEMORY];
    }

private void charge(APDU apdu) {        
    byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
    byte numBytes = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC];
    byte byteRead = (byte) (apdu.setIncomingAndReceive());

    if ((numBytes != 2) || (byteRead != 2)) {
        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_LENGTH);
    }

    short chargeAmount = (short) ((short) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA] << (short) 8) | (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA + 1]));

    if ((chargeAmount > MAX_BALANCE) || (chargeAmount < (short) 0)) {
        ISOException.throwIt(SW_INVALID_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT);
    }

    if ((short) (balance + chargeAmount) > MAX_BALANCE) {
        ISOException.throwIt(SW_MAX_BALANCE_EXCEEDED);
    }
    JCSystem.beginTransaction();
    balance = (short) (balance - chargeAmount);
    JCSystem.commitTransaction();
}
```

Comment: OK, so you added transactions, but this has *nothing* to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

When the *simulator* restarts? Normally Java Card simulators keep both persistent and transient memory in RAM. Use reset (requesting ATR) instead of stopping the simulator to perform a "card tear".

Comment: yes if i run the program again, program reinstall always.. so persitent data dissappered..

Comment: So how is your answer correct and mine isn't? You had trouble viewing the data after a simulator restart. How does the code in your answer fix this?

Comment: when i restart device, i cant see my applet in simulator. but i send "resume" command or right-click and say "resume" i can see my  applet run!

Comment: I'm glad you've got something working Savas, but I don't see any connection between your accepted answer and the original question.

Comment: thanks for your warn. i didnt discern that. i edited it. thanks again.